# Yii2 Compare Validator alert not disappear

Tags: validation, passwords, compare, yii2, comparevalidator

I type a password and then I repeat it on repeat password  field but red alert didn't disappear, and when I click submit button it was success and no error validation.
How to make compare alert disappear when I repeated password?

Here's my rules code in model

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        ['username', 'filter', 'filter' => 'trim'],
        ['username', 'required'],
        ['username', 'unique', 'targetClass' => '\common\models\User', 'message' => 'This username has already been taken.'],
        ['username', 'string', 'min' => 2, 'max' => 255],

        ['email', 'filter', 'filter' => 'trim'],
        ['email', 'required'],
        ['email', 'email'],
        ['email', 'unique', 'targetClass' => '\common\models\User', 'message' => 'This email address has already been taken.'],

        ['password', 'required'],
        ['password','compare'],
        ['password', 'string', 'min' => 6],
        ['password_repeat','safe']

    ];
}
```

and my form

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>

<h3>Your Account</h3>
<?= $form->field($modelUser, 'username')->textInput(['maxlength' => 45, 'class' => 'input-xlarge form-control']) ?>

<?= $form->field($modelUser, 'password')->passwordInput(['class' => 'form-control input-xlarge']) ?>

<?= $form->field($modelUser, 'password_repeat')->passwordInput(['class' => 'form-control input-xlarge']) ?>
<button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Continue</button>

<?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
```

and here's my screenshot
[image: yii2 compare validation]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In my case I just changed password validation from this:

```
['password','compare'],
```

to this:

```
['password_repeat', 'compare', 'compareAttribute' => 'password'],
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understood you correctly: you type the first password and, as you change focus to the other field (password_repeat), the form already shows an error message even though you haven't even typed the second field. If it's that, you could disable client validation, so that the data would be validated only after you submit the form. To do so, you could add the following to your **ActiveForm** initialization (it's an option):

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(['enableClientValidation' => false']);?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just only needed this line:

```
[['password_repeat'], 'compare', 'compareAttribute' => 'password', 'message' => 'Your error message']
```